# While executing shell scripts, how to know which line number it's executing,

Tags: bash, shell

While executing shell scripts, how to know which line number it's executing, do  have write a wrapper , where i can execute a shell scripts from a shell scripts and to know which line number it's executing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the `PS4` variable to cause `set -x` output to include the line number:

```
PS4=':${LINENO}+'
set -x
```

This will put the line number before each line as it executes:

```
:4+command here
:5+other command
```

It's important to have some sigil character (such as a `+` in my examples) after your variable expansions in `PS4`, because that last character is repeated to show nesting depth. That is, if you call a function, and that function invokes a command, the output from `set -x` will report it like so:

```
:3+++command run within a function called from a function
:8++command run within a function
:19+line after the function was called
```

If multiple files are involved in running your script, you might want to include the `BASH_SOURCE` variable as opposed to only `LINENO` (assuming this really is a bash script, as opposed to `/bin/sh` -- be sure your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`!):

```
PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+'
set -x
```

Comment: You said "the last character is repeated to show nesting depth", but `man bash` instead says "The first character of PS4 is replicated  multiple  times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection."

Comment: What do you understand "levels of indirection" to mean in this context? Describing stack-frame depth in that way is indeed not the most direct bit of nomenclature, but it is nonetheless the meaning at hand.

Comment: @LucianWischik, ...see also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips#use_shell_debug_output

Answer (score 6):

Bash has a special variable `$LINENO` which does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$LINENO"
echo "$LINENO"
echo "$LINENO"
```

Demo:

```
$ ./lineno
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/sh -x
```

will report the lines as they're executed (the `-x` option, to be clear). It won't give you the *line number*, but report the actual line.

An alternative, but more painful, approach is to use a trap handler, as documented [here](http://phaq.phunsites.net/2010/11/22/trap-errors-exit-codes-and-line-numbers-within-a-bash-script/).